# How to accomplish this layout in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

Why are the floating elements are not properly arranged? My images have some white space and I have no idea from where it comes from.

The desired look:

[image]

The code:

```css
.inner-wrapper { float: left; width: 100%; color: #000; }

.feature-1 { float: right; margin: 0 auto; width: 50%; height: auto; }
.aside-image-1 { float: left; margin: 0 auto; height: auto; width: 50%; }

.feature-2 { float: left; margin: 0 auto; width: 50%; height: auto; }
.aside-image-2 { float: right; margin: 0 auto; height: auto; width: 50%; }

.feature-3 { float: right; margin: 0 auto; width: 50%; height: auto; }
.aside-image-3 { float: left; margin: 0 auto; height: auto; width: 50%; clear: both; }
```

```html
<section class="inner-wrapper">
    <aside class="aside-image-1">
        <img src="https://s13.postimg.org/xsvgi16hv/feature_1.jpg" title="someText" alt="someText">
    </aside>
    <article class="feature-1">
        <h3>In-Store Interactive Tablet</h3>
        <p>Shoppers can use Sellr's Help Me Choose feature to</p>
    </article>
</section>
<section class="inner-wrapper">
    <aside class="aside-image-2">
        <img src="https://s13.postimg.org/t89a33msj/feature_2.jpg" title="someText" alt="someText">
    </aside>
    <article class="feature-2">
        <h3>In-Store Interactive Tablet</h3>
        <p>Shoppers can use Sellr's Help Me Choose feature to</p>
    </article>
</section>
<section class="inner-wrapper">
    <aside class="aside-image-3">
        <img src="https://s13.postimg.org/9ex6ae9er/feature_3.jpg" title="someText" alt="someText">
    </aside>
    <article class="feature-3">
        <h3>In-Store Interactive Tablet</h3>
        <p>Shoppers can use Sellr's Help Me Choose feature to</p>
    </article>
</section>
```

Comment: Sometimes inline IMG's will have small whitespace below them. Remove this by making them `display:block`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this...

Make the image's width 100% and Text-align center

```css
.inner-wrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  color: #000;
}
.feature-1 {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.aside-image-1 {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
.feature-2 {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
}
.aside-image-2 {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
.feature-3 {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.aside-image-3 {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: auto;
  width: 50%;
  clear: both;
}
.aside-image-1 img {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.aside-image-2 img {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.aside-image-3 img {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<section class="inner-wrapper">
  <aside class="aside-image-1">
    <img src="https://s13.postimg.org/xsvgi16hv/feature_1.jpg" title="someText" alt="someText">
  </aside>
  <article class="feature-1">
    <h3>In-Store Interactive Tablet</h3>
    <p>Shoppers can use Sellr's Help Me Choose feature to</p>
  </article>
</section>
<section class="inner-wrapper">
  <aside class="aside-image-2">
    <img src="https://s13.postimg.org/t89a33msj/feature_2.jpg" title="someText" alt="someText">
  </aside>
  <article class="feature-2">
    <h3>In-Store Interactive Tablet</h3>
    <p>Shoppers can use Sellr's Help Me Choose feature to</p>
  </article>
</section>
<section class="inner-wrapper">
  <aside class="aside-image-3">
    <img src="https://s13.postimg.org/9ex6ae9er/feature_3.jpg" title="someText" alt="someText">
  </aside>
  <article class="feature-3">
    <h3>In-Store Interactive Tablet</h3>
    <p>Shoppers can use Sellr's Help Me Choose feature to</p>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks bro @jafarbtech

Answer (score 2):

add some property to your **image tag**

```
img{
  width:100%;
  }
```

```css
.inner-wrapper { float: left; width: 100%; color: #000; }

.feature-1 { float: right; margin: 0 auto; width: 50%; height: auto; }
.aside-image-1 { float: left; margin: 0 auto; height: auto; width: 50%; }

.feature-2 { float: left; margin: 0 auto; width: 50%; height: auto; }
.aside-image-2 { float: right; margin: 0 auto; height: auto; width: 50%; }

.feature-3 { float: right; margin: 0 auto; width: 50%; height: auto; }
.aside-image-3 { float: left; margin: 0 auto; height: auto; width: 50%; clear: both; }
img{
  width:100%;
  }
```

```html
<section class="inner-wrapper">
   <aside class="aside-image-1">
    <img src="https://s13.postimg.org/xsvgi16hv/feature_1.jpg" title="someText" alt="someText">
   </aside>
   <article class="feature-1">
    <h3>In-Store Interactive Tablet</h3>
    <p>Shoppers can use Sellr's Help Me Choose feature to</p>
   </article>
  </section>
  <section class="inner-wrapper">
   <aside class="aside-image-2">
    <img src="https://s13.postimg.org/t89a33msj/feature_2.jpg" title="someText" alt="someText">
   </aside>
   <article class="feature-2">
    <h3>In-Store Interactive Tablet</h3>
    <p>Shoppers can use Sellr's Help Me Choose feature to</p>
   </article>
  </section>
  <section class="inner-wrapper">
   <aside class="aside-image-3">
    <img src="https://s13.postimg.org/9ex6ae9er/feature_3.jpg" title="someText" alt="someText">
   </aside>
   <article class="feature-3">
    <h3>In-Store Interactive Tablet</h3>
    <p>Shoppers can use Sellr's Help Me Choose feature to</p>
   </article>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
body{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
```

and images width should be 100%;

```css
.inner-wrapper { float: left; width: 100%; color: #000; }

.feature-1 { float: right; margin: 0 auto; width: 50%; height: auto; }
.aside-image-1 { float: left; margin: 0 auto; height: auto; width: 50%; }

.feature-2 { float: left; margin: 0 auto; width: 50%; height: auto; }
.aside-image-2 { float: right; margin: 0 auto; height: auto; width: 50%; }

.feature-3 { float: right; margin: 0 auto; width: 50%; height: auto; }
.aside-image-3 { float: left; margin: 0 auto; height: auto; width: 50%; clear: both; }
```

```html
<section class="inner-wrapper">
   <aside class="aside-image-1">
    <img src="https://s13.postimg.org/xsvgi16hv/feature_1.jpg"  style="width:100%" title="someText" alt="someText">
   </aside>
   <article class="feature-1">
    <h3>In-Store Interactive Tablet</h3>
    <p>Shoppers can use Sellr's Help Me Choose feature to</p>
   </article>
  </section>
  <section class="inner-wrapper">
   <aside class="aside-image-2">
    <img src="https://s13.postimg.org/t89a33msj/feature_2.jpg" style="width:100%" title="someText" alt="someText">
   </aside>
   <article class="feature-2">
    <h3>In-Store Interactive Tablet</h3>
    <p>Shoppers can use Sellr's Help Me Choose feature to</p>
   </article>
  </section>
  <section class="inner-wrapper">
   <aside class="aside-image-3">
    <img src="https://s13.postimg.org/9ex6ae9er/feature_3.jpg"  style="width:100%" title="someText" alt="someText">
   </aside>
   <article class="feature-3">
    <h3>In-Store Interactive Tablet</h3>
    <p>Shoppers can use Sellr's Help Me Choose feature to</p>
   </article>
  </section>
```